# Google App Engine downloads php instead of interpreting it

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Here is my .yaml

```
application: awshw
version: 1
module: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /php/lookup.php
  script: lookup.php

- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

and here is the ajax call in my index.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/lookup.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        symbol: req.term
    },
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        //document.write(settings.url);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);


    }
});
```

Normally the lookup.php returns json when running from localhost as I wanted but when running on GAE I get the source code of lookup.php as the result of the ajax query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry never mind , I think it had to do with google app engine not properly updated it worked now.